# Can you standarize the whitespaces of the source code?

Tags: listings, minted, sourcecode, white-space

I want to know if there is a option to set all the whitespaces in my source code.

The whitespaces in my CPP code do not look uniform. Sometimes I leave a space before and after the = sign, sometimes I dont. The same with loops etc.

Is there any parameter that makes the whitespaces, formatting, more "uniform"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is this a question about tex typesetting, or a question about settings in a C++ source code editor? You have tagged listings and minted, which are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `listings` and `minted` packages do not offer the functionality to reformat/prettify the code. However, a possible solution is to call an external formatter first and print the result. For C++ a formatter that handles spaces is `clang-format`, which is part of the Clang compiler suite.

From within LaTeX you can use the `shellesc` package for an easy cross-platform way of executing external programs. This package requires the `shell-escape` command line option, which is also needed for `minted`.

Example badly formatted C++ file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   int a= 3;
   int b =4;
   if( a==b){
      std::cout  << "no" <<std::endl;
      }else{ std::cout << "yes"<<std::endl;
      }
return 0;
}
```

LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{shellesc}

\newcommand{\reformatcpp}[1]{%
   \ShellEscape{clang-format #1 > #1.tmp}%
   \inputminted{c++}{#1.tmp}%
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Original file}
\inputminted{c++}{yourfile.cc}
\section*{Reformatted}
\reformatcpp{yourfile.cc}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]